# Uploading an MVC site into another MVC sites' subdirectory hosted on Register.com

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller, web-hosting

I've been looking all over the web and stackoverflow since yesterday. I have two websites hosted by Register.com (their tech support wasn't very helpful).
I have website1.com up and running and I'm in the process of uploading website2.com. Both are MVC5 .Net framework websites.

Register.com gives you domain pointers when you add websites to your hosting package; so, website2.com is pointing to a specific directory inside website1.com.

I have connected to the remote server via IIS Manager and have activated the directory to be an application and have uploaded the new site to the new directory using Visual Studio 2013 FTP mode (same as the first one).

The problem is that when you go to www.website2.com, none of the code/css/javascript is being rendered and you only get unformatted text on screen.

I'm at my wit's end with this and feel I have tried everything thus far.
    Does anyone have experience hosting MVC/.NET websites with register.com/web.com?

Thanks a lot!

FYI, I just checked. If I go to www.website1.com/website2 the website 2 compiles and displays properly. However, the www.website2.com still shows unformatted text.

Comment: You can start by checking what domain the css/js are being served from and what their path is. My guess is one of those is wrong. An easy way to do that would be to check the "network" tab in Chrome/Firefox developer tools and look for the files that serve up a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: jquery and css don't ever load because they're "bundled" in BundleConfig.cs and since it looks like that never executes, no styles are generated. I suppose I could put links to the scripts directly onto the page, but that doesn't really solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

For Your case I would suggest to user Area. Make your websiet 2 Area of your website 1. So you dont need do create folder and upload app in it.

Comment: What do you mean by creating website "areas"?

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't the answer I was looking for, but as a workaround I removed all of razor lines that rendered the CSS/JavaScript files (eg @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") ) and replaced them with hard-coded links to the files/CDNs.
Again, not the perfect solution, but it got the job done.